# React native share array with Add remove to all other pages

Tags: react-native

how to store React native array globally and insert, delete and display data from anywhere? (Like shopping cart)

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried.

Comment: How to Store array globally in react native and get data in any page with push and pop data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The easiest way would be to use AsyncStorage to store your array.
  **[React Native Async Storage](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage)** is now a standalone package that you will have to install and link.
- If you are using redux, it may make more sense to use [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) to store your array and not mess up your app logic.